# How to write a parameter-driven macro?

Tags: plain-tex

An specific question is as follows:

> I hope that I can define a macro that can switch to different typefaces. We assume that this macro is named `\myfonts`, so, if I type `{\myfonts throughout his life, Einstein published hundreds of books and articles.}`, the typeface will be the default `Minion Pro`. But if I pass a parameter to that macro, for example, `{\myfonts{palatino} ...}`, it will become the `Palatino` typeface.

I have no idea to this question now.

In LaTeX, if you say `\documentclass{article}`, it will take `a4paper` and `10pt` as the default, but if you type `\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{article}`, it will be changed into `b5paper` and `11pt`. I am curious about this: How can I achieve that?

Comment: You have tagged this plain-tex do you want it for plain, not for latex? also does it have to be that syntax, which is problematic, as there is no way of knowing that the following `{` is a argument delimiter rather than a following group `\myfonts {\bf zzz } xxx` you probbaly want to take this as no-parameter form. A syntax such as `[]` or `<>` delimited optional argument as in latex is much less likely to have this problem.

Comment: Also, is your intent to switch to the new font momentarily (inline font change, with a clear beginning and end), or to arbitrarily change to new font for an indefinite period?

Comment: do you mean how can you achieve that in latex or how you can achieve it in plain?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean that how can I achive the macros in this form (like `\documentclass` and so on, only a form, it can be any macro in this form) in plain tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the macro in this form is very useful when I want to give some options (of course, I can choose not to use this options, so it will use the default values).

Comment: probably you should ask a different question as the main part of that is dealing with comma separated lists (for which latex has several macros but in plain you need to write something, there will be lots of examples on this site though)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

using `[]` delimited argument and the fonts in plain by default:

```
\def\myfonts{\futurelet\tmp\xmyfonts}
\def\xmyfonts{\ifx\tmp[\expandafter\argmyfonts\else\noargmyfonts\fi}
\def\argmyfonts[#1]{\csname myfonts#1\endcsname}
\def\noargmyfonts{\rm}
\def\myfontsa{\tt}
\def\myfontsb{\it}


{\myfonts abc de}
{\myfonts[a] abc de}
{\myfonts[b] abc de}

\bye
```

Comment: thanks, David. I think the `\futurelet` and `\expandafter` is what I want, but I can't achieve this construct. Now, I am learing this method from your code:-)

Comment: @TimLi You should be able to use it as posted but just define `\myfontspalatino` etc as the internal command do do whatever you need to switch to that font.

Comment: yeah. I have edited my question, the added part is the reason why I want to ask you this question.